# Loading indicator around stacklayout

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a loading indicator/spinning animation around a StackLayout, as you can see in the image below, the indicator color must change according to the direction, the indicator is going around the lane, wherever the indicator goes the line seems to fade. Its like a spinning animation around the layout.

[image: Loading indicator around StackLayout]

I have tried to create a custom stack layout and add some border animation but with no success.

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom frame instead? Then just adding a Gradient Effect to the frame?

Comment: Here's some helpful links I found for u https://github.com/sthewissen/Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58818/how-to-animate-change-of-background-color

Have a look and generally a frame can wrap the Stacklayout so you'll just need to animate the Background

Comment: @Azurry I haven't tried with a frame, I could give it a shot, but I don't know much about animations. The links you have posted seem interesting, I will give it a short, thank you!

Comment: Hope you figure out, Make sure to post for us! id love to see this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom renderer to set the gradient border of `frame` instead of `stacklayout`.

MyFrame.cs

```
public class MyFrame:Frame
{
}
```

MyFrameRenderer.cs

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyFrame), typeof(MyFrameRenderer))]
namespace GradientBorder.Droid
{
 public class MyFrameRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<Frame>
   {
    public MyFrameRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.Gradient);
    }
  }
}
```

Gradient.xml in Android Resource Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >
  <gradient

      android:angle="360"
      android:centerColor="#edecbb"
      android:endColor="#e6e217"
      android:gradientRadius="360"
      android:startColor="#edeb72"
      android:type="sweep" />
  <corners android:radius="10dp" />
  <!--<stroke
      android:width="2dp"
      android:color="#ff207d94" />-->
</shape>
</item>
<item
   android:bottom="5dp"
  android:left="5dp"
  android:right="5dp"
  android:top="5dp">
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >
  <solid android:color="#fff" />
</shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

MainPage.xml

```
  <StackLayout Padding="50" BackgroundColor="Gray">
    <local:MyFrame>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button />
            <Label Text="Hello" />
        </StackLayout>
    </local:MyFrame>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]