# How to draw just the borders of a rectangle?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, mobile

I'm customizing a Xamarin.forms.control. I want to put it inside a "box", we can call it rectangle.So all I want is the border.

```
this.Control.SetBackground(d);
```

here d has to be a Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable. How can I create such a drawable,just the borders of a box?

Comment: Frame with transparent background color.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a frame, you can layer two [rectangles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.graphics.drawables.shapes.rectshape?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12) on top of each other, where the margin between the two would be your desired border thickness. The front rectangle would be your background, the back would be your border.

Read about the shapes here: [android.graphics.drawables.shapedrawable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.graphics.drawables.shapedrawable?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12)

Alternatively, you could probably adjust the padding or margins of whatever container you are using to allow for a border like effect as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the shape with xaml. Create a `Gradient.xml` in Android Resource Drawable and set it with `SetBackgroundResource`.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
   <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
   <gradient

    android:angle="360"
    android:centerColor="#edecbb"
    android:endColor="#e6e217"
    android:gradientRadius="360"
    android:startColor="#edeb72"
    android:type="sweep" />
   <corners android:radius="10dp" />
   <!--<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#ff207d94" />-->
   </shape>
   </item>
   <item
     android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
     android:top="5dp">
   <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#fff" />
   </shape>
   </item>

   </layer-list>
```

[image]

For more details, you could refer to the case link i done before. [Loading indicator around stacklayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296716/loading-indicator-around-stacklayout/60312870#60312870)

Comment: i dont know any android xml , only xaml...

Comment: If you do not use the xml, you could not do it without `Drawable`.   In your Forms proejct, create this xml file inside Android> Resource> Drawable folder.  Create your custom control and then set it as background resource via custom renderer. You could check the whole code i done before in the link i provided.

Comment: If you have any issue for this, feel free to let me know.